# ASP.Net project upgrades from targeting 4.5 .NET Framework to 4.6.1 reports error of "AL1078"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-4.5, .net-4.6.1

The project was built fine with `4.5` but fails with following error when changed to target `4.6.1`.

The assemblies the project dependents on are all target `4.6.1`.

I tried to uncheck the `Sign the assembly` but the error remained. It doesn't seem to related to signing at all.

```
error AL1078: Error signing assembly -- The keyset is not defined.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a corrupt file on your machine.  Beware that the assembly linker doesn't just check your .snk file, it also checks the strong name in any reference assemblies.  Including the .NET ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try to [recreate your `.snk` file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx) from `AssemblyInfo` with `sn.exe` with argument `-k c:\keyfile.snk`. Then check your `AssemblyInfo`:

```
[assembly:AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("keyfile.snk")]
```

Note that sometimes the restart for VS is required to handle the keypair creation for the project.